# How to create a window in JavaFX with only the origional looked close button?

Tags: javafx

I was trying to find a way to create a stage with `StageStyle.DECORATED` but with no minimize or maximize button and with the origional look of the close button. I have tried with `StageStyle.UTILITY` but that looks pretty weird.

I would like to have some window likes this:
(This is an window from intelliJ)
[IntelliJ Open URL Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCwGq.png)

Anyone have some idea about this?
Thanks!

Comment: don't quite get it: you want a stage with only the close decoration and StageStyle.UTILITY with is a window with minimal decorations (== close button) looks weird? Why?

Comment: @kleopatra if i'm not mistaken, I believe he/she is referring to the CSS style of the window. When a `Stage` or a `Dialog` is styled as `StageStyle.UTILITY` the window itself change its CSS and look different from a normal stage. If you display two stages one using `StageStyle. UTILITY` and one normal you will notice the difference (example close button color, window border color etc.). At least using Java 8 running on Window 10 I can see the difference.

Comment: @JKostikiadis indeed looking different, fx10 as well - thanks for info :)

Comment: @kleopatra to be honest I find it more like a bug rather than a feature. But maybe there is a reason behind it.

Comment: @JKostikiadis Exactly, That's what I mean, It looks Ugly (forgive me using that word) haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default StageStyle of a Stage or a Dialog is `StageStyle.DECORATED` and reading the [StageStyle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/stage/StageStyle.html) you can see :

- **DECORATED** : Defines a normal Stage style with a solid white background and platform decorations.
- **UTILITY**   : Defines a Stage style with a solid white background and minimal platform decorations used for a utility window.

So from the above description the reason you see some difference in the stage is the "minimal platform decorations" which of course may be unnoticeable or not depending on the platform you or your client is using. To my knowledge, there is not any way to access or change that decoration because the operating system is responsible of how the title bar and the borders of your application are displayed. The only way I know you can achieve it is to create your own custom stage and apply any CSS you want. To do that you have to set your `StageStyle.UNDECORATED` and create the title bar from scratch.

Although in your specific case you do not need to use a stage. You could achieve this using a custom Dialog which doesn't have minimize and maximize buttons ( On Java 8 at least, but I believe it's the same for a latest versions as well ) here is an example :

```
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        String input = showInputDialog();
        System.out.println("User Input : " + input);
        Platform.exit();
    }

    private String showInputDialog() {
        // Create the custom dialog.
        Dialog<String> dialog = new Dialog<String>();
        dialog.setTitle("Open URL");

        // Remove the header
        dialog.setHeaderText(null);

        // If you want to add an icon to the Dialog
        // dialog.setGraphic(new
        // ImageView(this.getClass().getResource("logo.png").toExternalForm()));

        // Set the button types.
        ButtonType okButtonType = new ButtonType("OK", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(okButtonType, ButtonType.CANCEL);

        // Create a VBox to store your controls
        VBox mainPane = new VBox(5);

        Label promptLabel = new Label("Specify URL :");

        HBox urlPane = new HBox();
        urlPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        urlPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        TextField urlField = new TextField();
        Button searchButton = new Button("Search");
        searchButton.setOnAction(e->{
            // open a FileChooser etc and do something
        });

        urlPane.getChildren().addAll(urlField, searchButton);
        mainPane.getChildren().addAll(promptLabel, urlField);

        HBox.setHgrow(urlField, Priority.ALWAYS);

        // Enable/Disable OK button depending on whether a urlField was filled.
        Node confirmationButton = dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(okButtonType);
        confirmationButton.disableProperty().bind(urlField.textProperty().isEmpty());

        // set the content of the Dialog
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(mainPane);

        // set dialog return value
        dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
            if (dialogButton == okButtonType) {
                return urlField.getText();
            }
            return null;
        });

        Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();

        if (result.isPresent()) {
            return result.get();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The result :

[image]

Comment: I have to say Thank you so much, this actually helps me a lot when to work around with the `StageStyle.UTILITY`, and It looks much better than before. I firmly believe this solution will help others in the future, thanks again ;)